# Extracting selector variable names from JSON data

Tags: javascript, wdio-v5

Given the following json:

```
{
  "contract": [
    {"fieldName": "contractYear", "fieldValue": "2020"},
    ...
  ],
  "ruleSet": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

And the following:

```
staticCompany.contract.forEach(index => {
  if (this.index.fieldName.getText() == index.fieldValue) {
    validationCount ++;
  }
});
```

I know for a fact that the this. operator will not like what I am trying to do.  Is there a way to extract the fieldName such that I can use it to hit the selector of the same name?

I am doing this in Node 12.13 on wdio v5.

Comment: Did you mean `this[index]` instead of `this.index`?

Comment: there's no need for `this` at all - replace `this.index` with simply `index` and this will work. But `index` is a poor choice of name for the actual array element

Comment: actually, that probably isn't what you want, on reflection - but I have no idea what you *do* want. Could you edit your question to make the input and expected output more clear?

Comment: Will the `fieldName `  value ever actually equal the `fieldValue` value?

Comment: In your `forEach()` statement, `this` referrs to the `window`. Also, the for each is only passing in the index number of the array. If you want to see the values in the `forEach()` you need to pass the element like this: `forEach((element) => { ... } )`. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `forEach()` statement, `this` referrs to the window, so you won't want to use that.

Also, the for each is only passing in the index number of the array. If you want to see the values in the `forEach()` you need to include the element as well (Okay, technically in your for each, `index` is bringing back the element because it is listed first, but syntactically it gets confusing if you are using `index` when it isn't actually the index).

All of these are valid options:

```
forEach((element) => { ... } )
forEach((element, index) => { ... } )
forEach((element, index, array) => { ... } )
```

See [MDN: Array.ForEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for more info.

In the snippet below, I added in a second Object element into the `contract` array to show you how you can access each Object element in that array, and get the values from it.

```js
const staticCompany = {
  "contract": [{
      "fieldName": "contractYear",
      "fieldValue": "2020"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "contractYear",
      "fieldValue": "2021"
    },
  ],
  "ruleSet": []
}

staticCompany.contract.forEach((element, index) => {
  console.log({
    index: index,
    fieldName: element.fieldName,
    fieldValue: element.fieldValue
  })
});
```